# Pass RVO object to std::vector::emplace_back

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

Considering the following array:

```
std::vector<Foo> arr;
arr.emplace_back(calculate_foo());
```

`emplace_back` benefits from eliminating a temporary object since it's arguments are passed in place on the new constructed element (so here emplace_back would trigger the move or copy constructor) `Foo(foo)`

The code above creates of course a temporary object in `calculate_foo`, and than gets either copied or moved to the new array, depending of the constructors of Foo.

Is there any chance to make this faster and eliminate the temporary object?

Comment: It passes the argument(s) to the constructor.  Which constructor depends on the arguments passed.  You could defined a constructor for `Foo` that takes a dummy argument and then calls calculate_foo() in the constructor.

Comment: @RichardCritten This should be the answer.

Comment: That sounds awesome! Can you make this the answer?

Comment: @RichardCritten What do you mean by _dummy argument_?

Comment: @nada: `enum DUMMY{FOO1};` constructor would be `Foo(DUMMY) {*this = calculate_foo();} emplace_back(DUMMY::FOO1);`

Comment: It would then benefit from RVO and everyone is happy

Comment: @DanielStephens Why not a constructor without arguments?

Comment: How does `*this = calculate_foo();` benefit from RVO?

Comment: I avoided this being an answer because to me, my comment, does not pass the _"least surprise"_ and  _"premature optimisation"_ test/rule.  If the OP wishes to answer their own question using my suggestion I would have no problem.

Comment: @DanielStephens That has the effect of calling the move assignment operator, still creating a temporary in between. In addition it constructs `this` with default initialized members first, which the original code does not do.

Comment: Duh, agreed! @ eerorika @ uneven_mark So that wouldn't be a real benefit then

Comment: @RichardCritten It is not clear to me how what you are saying can be done using `calculate_foo`, assuming it has return type `Foo`, which must always be materialized somewhere in the constructor/assignment operator parameters. #DanielStephens: The benefit of `emplace_back` comes into play if you don't pass a fully constructed `Foo`, but only arguments that are needed to construct it.

Comment: I wouldn't care too much about an additional move constructor call. It is only called at a source code level. An optimizer may completely optimize it away if it resolves it as unnecessary. See, e.g., [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ecfnba). In the generated assembly, there are no `Foo` construtor calls. They have been completely inlined and the argument of converting construcor is directly passed to `_M_realloc_insert`. There is, therefore, no move constructor involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid creating the temporary argument for the constructor of `Foo` with `emplace_back`. If you use an argument of type `Foo`, then that is the temporary object that will be passed to the constructor of the emplaced object. In this case, `push_back` would be equally efficient.

To really take advantage of emplacement, your type needs to have a constructor that takes some lightweight argument(s), that can be used to construct the more expensive object. This way, only temporaries are the light weight object(s). In order to emplace directly from a return value, that constructor can only take a single argument.

Example:

```
struct ExpensiveMove {
    explicit ExpensiveMove(double d) {
         std::cout << "construct\n";
         std::fill(arr.begin(), arr.end(), d);
    }

    ExpensiveMove(const ExpensiveMove&) { std::cout << "expensive copy\n"; }
    ExpensiveMove(ExpensiveMove&&) { std::cout << "expensive move\n"; }
    ExpensiveMove& operator=(const ExpensiveMove&) { std::cout << "expensive copy ass\n"; return *this; }
    ExpensiveMove& operator=(ExpensiveMove&&) { std::cout << "expensive move ass\n"; return *this; }
    std::array<double, 1024> arr;
};

double calculate()
{
    return 4.2;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<ExpensiveMove> arr;
    arr.emplace_back(calculate());
}
```

No temporaries of type `ExpensiveMove` in this example. There is a temporary double, which doesn't matter.